# Does bittorrent seeding broadcast chunks if there are no peers

Tags: bittorrent

This should be a pretty straightforward question.

If am seeding a torrent and there are no peers, do chunks continue to be broadcast? I believe the answer is no, but my research usually brought up definitions and differences between seeders and leechers.

Comment: Leechers request which chunk they need from the seeders, no leechers, no requests, no data sent.

Comment: @ElTurner a 'leecher' is a 'peer' who minimizes the data they share with other peers. i.e. disconnects when they complete with a ratio of less than 1.0.  A 'seeder' is a 'peer' who has 100% of the torrent data.

Comment: Sorry, I use the term interchangeably when I talk about P2P. But yes my comment should read "Peers" Not "Leechers".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there are no peers for the torrent you are seeding then no chunks are sent.

Answer (score 1):

No, it couldn't "continue" doing so, because it never did that *in the first place* – BitTorrent does not use broadcast (nor multicast); data is sent individually to each peer.

Comment: I think the OP means transferred over the network rather than the strict IP term of Broadcast.